# Ethereum transaction events listener with AWS lambda

Tags: web3js, events

We are using ERC20 tokens in our application for our transactions. We are having a hard time as to how to keep track of pending transactions and users token balance. Ideally, we want to notify user as soon as the transaction is confirmed on the blockchain. For this, we tried using web3 WebSockets but we noticed that after few hours of running servers, some contract events missed out and users didnt get any confirmation notification.

Can anyone guide on this as how to effectively listen for contract events or pending transactions especially in a production environment?

Very recently I have been thinking of using AWS lambda with cloud watch for listening events but couldn't get any help on this.

Answer (score 4):

You can setup an app on [Alchemy](https://alchemy.com) and use their Notify service. It allows you to setup a webhook that fires when an Ether or ERC20 token transaction happens for one or more addresses. You can set the webhook to call an AWS Lambda function and do whatever you need there.